# Чтение данных в DataFrame из множественных txt-файлов

Tags: python, apache-spark

Документация модуля PySpark не дает однозначного ответа как загрузить 10000 txt файлов в один df в питоне.

Есть ли команда или понятный набор команд, как прочитать из папки с 10000 txt-файлов в df ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример чтения множества CSV файлов в Spark DataFrame:

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/path/to/*.txt")
```

или

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/path/to/*.txt")
```

В идеале файлы должны храниться на HDFS, тогда эта операция может выполняться параллельно в кластере многими "executors".

---

Для чтения JSON файлов:

```
df = spark.read.json("file:///tmp/data*.txt")
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. В моих условиях кластеров нет, есть только разрозненные источники и парсинг.

Comment: Ошибку дает. Наверное нужно еще как-то энкодинг настроить?

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @StepanSokol, по умолчанию Spark ожидает и читает все в UTF-8 кодировке. Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002651/how-to-parse-csv-file-with-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: df = spark.read().option("header", "true")\
                             .option("encoding", "UTF-8").csv("C:\Users\Sokol\Desktop\Python Work\new_iteration\*.txt")

Comment: И все равно 

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: можете выложить небольшой пример файла в вашей оригинальной кодировке на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/qQXu5TOLz9V_dg

Вот txt-шник, который внутри выглядит как json

Comment: а зачем вам Spark если у вас нет кластера (проще и быстрее будет в Pandas обработать)? Или есть подозрение, что ваш DataFrame может не поместиться в память?

Comment: Проблема все таки решилась старым методом через спец.утилитку специально написанную для этого